# Question in Field Analysis

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm in an analysis course this semester and it has been a while since I've done proofs. I'm having a hard time coming up with ideas for these questions. I have ideas for a and b, but I am completely lost with c. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer each of the following by establishing a 1-1 correspondence with a set of known cardinality.

a) Is the set of all functions from {0,1} to N countable or uncountable?

b) Is the set of all functions from N to {0,1} countable ot uncountable?

c) Given the set B, a subset of A of P(B) is called an antichain if no element of A is a subset of any other element of A. Does P(N) contain an uncountable antichain?

Comment: I think you should state your ideas for a) and b), and we can tell you if you're on the right track

Comment: "Field Analysis"?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a:** Establish a 1-1 correspondence with $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$.

**Hint for b:** Establish a 1-1 correspondence with $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$

**Hint for c:** Let $E$ denote the set of even numbers (in $\Bbb N$), and $F$ the set of odd numbers.

Let $f_E:\Bbb N \to E$ and $f_F:\Bbb N \to F$ be bijections.  For an element $S \in \mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, define $\Phi(S)$ to be the set
$$
\Phi(S) = \{f_E(s) : s \in S\} \cup \{f_F(t): t \notin S\} = f_E(S) \cup [O \setminus f_O(S)]
$$
I claim that the collection $\{\Phi(S): S \in \mathcal P(S)\}$ is an antichain, and that it has the same cardinality as $\mathcal P(S)$.

Comment: Thank you for the help with a and me. I am still having difficulty understanding c. I don't understand how a bijection is formed between the antichain and the P(N).

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Be more specific